# Python Facebook SDK: How to get response from request?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following code to publish photo but I don't know how to get response ID post. How to get it ?

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='mytoken', version='2.7')

graph.put_photo(image=open(r'E:\Facebook\myphoto.jpg', 'rb'), message='Cool'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Also, Facebook doesn't show photo in wall. It shows "no automatic alt text available". So, how to publish photo correctly ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [`put_photo()`](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-photo) should return JSON containing the ID and the post ID, however, it actually returns a dictionary, i.e the JSON has been decoded for you. Try this:

```
import json
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='mytoken', version='2.7')
photo = graph.put_photo(image=open(r'E:\Facebook\myphoto.jpg', 'rb'), message='Cool'.encode('utf-8')) 
print(photo)
print('id: {}'.format(photo['id']))
print('photo_id: {}'.format(photo['post_id']))
```